# how does java play with AMD Threadripper platform

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, amd-processor

There has been a lot of talks about application performance on AMD Threadripper CPUs like 2990WX https://level1techs.com/article/unlocking-2990wx-less-numa-aware-apps

I'm wondering if Java (Oracle JDK 8) handles multithreaded workloads like Linux (best performance) or like Windows (buggy kernel: worst performance). or does Java offload it to the operating system?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered comprehensively, as the details of how Java Threads are implemented are, well, details of the implementation, that is the JVM. There are multiple JVM implementations in use, each in multiple different versions, and I would be surprised if they all behaved the same way in that regard. However, most implementations probably use OS Threads one way or the other.

Comment: Oracle JDK 8, would that narrow it down? and I'm not looking for details just if someone here have access to a threadripper WX CPU and have some insights. just a high level answer.

Comment: Oracle JDK 8 uses OS threads.

Comment: @yole if you can provide a source for that claim, this would make a good answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that @yole was right with his comment and at least the Oracle JDK 8 uses a 1:1 mapping to OS Threads.

As shown in the [Java SE Technologies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/index.html), the JVM in use here is the Java HotSpot VM. Somewhat burried in a document about a change in how thread priorities are propagated in [the Java SE 8 technotes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/thread-priorities.html), I found the following statement:

> The Java HotSpot virtual machine currently associates each Java thread with a unique native thread. The relationship between the Java thread and the native thread is stable and persists for the lifetime of the Java thread.

"native" seems to imply "Operating System" within this context, as far as I can tell, as the text goes on discussing specifics about Solaris Kernel Threads/LWPs.

<sub>(I also found some historic references to early (pre-java 1.2) versions that used "Green Threads" fully simulated within the JVM, but it seems that is no longer in use)</sub>